# simple_captcha_valid? always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, captcha

I am using [simple_captcha](https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha/) in my rails 3 application. I have a form for requesting quote, But in my controller

```
if simple_captcha_valid?
```

always returns false.

The log says it gets null key value

```
SimpleCaptcha::SimpleCaptchaData Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `simple_captcha_data`.* FROM `simple_captcha_data` WHERE `simple_captcha_data`.`key` IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to the party here, but I ran into the same issue and opened a pull request on the repo to make captcha validation idempotent. Seems the captcha entry is deleted the first time you validate it, which is both surprising and obscured by the code (a predicate method calling a bang method internally). Make sure you're not validating your model more than once and you should be OK.